# Python convert dataframe to series. Showing repetitive column name

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have an excel file that I imported as dataframe but when I try to convert the dataframe into series. Something weird happens. The 'Sales' was the column name but now it's showing up side by side like this.

```
Date             
2015-01-01  Sales    14840.0
2015-02-01  Sales    14820.0
2015-03-01  Sales    17920.0
2015-04-01  Sales    19020.0
2015-05-01  Sales    20600.0
2015-06-01  Sales    13940.0
2015-07-01  Sales    14000.0
2015-08-01  Sales    15860.0
2015-09-01  Sales    17220.0
2015-10-01  Sales    20640.0
2015-11-01  Sales    31040.0
2015-12-01  Sales    30260.0
2016-01-01  Sales    17000.0
2016-02-01  Sales    18760.0
2016-03-01  Sales    22220.0
2016-04-01  Sales    17960.0
2016-05-01  Sales    18640.0
2016-06-01  Sales    21100.0
2016-07-01  Sales    22180.0
2016-08-01  Sales    25700.0
2016-09-01  Sales    26606.0
2016-10-01  Sales    21980.0
2016-11-01  Sales    48160.0
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
       Date      Sales
0   2015-01-01  14840.0 
1   2015-02-01  14820.0
2   2015-03-01  17920.0 
3   2015-04-01  19020.0 
4   2015-05-01  20600.0
```

The code i use:

```
df = pd.read_excel('sales.xlsx', index_col=[0], squeeze = True)
df = df.stack()
```

Comment: Does `df.set_index('Data')['Sales']` work?

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva no it does not. How would you normally convert data frame to series?

Comment: @PiCubed what do you mean it does not work? Based on your sample data `df.set_index('Data')['Sales']` is the correct answer. For example, if you do `type(df.set_index('Date')['Sales'])` you will get `pandas.core.series.Series`

Comment: There's a mistype in my code. Replace `Data` for `Date`. It's supposed to work. Also, you need either read the file without `index_col=[0]`, or just type `df['Sales']` instead of `df.set_index('Data')['Sales']`.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your xlsx file does not have an index column? so your problem would be solved by removing `index_col=[0]` from your code.

```
df = pd.read_excel('sales.xlsx', squeeze = True)
df = df.stack()

Out:
    
df = 
0  Date     2015-01-01 00:00:00
   Sales                  14840
1  Date     2015-02-01 00:00:00
   Sales                  14820
2  Date     2015-03-01 00:00:00
   Sales                  17920
3  Date     2015-04-01 00:00:00
   Sales                  19020
4  Date     2015-05-01 00:00:00
   Sales                  20600
```